# Don't open vim when I exit pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, vim

When I'm working on a LaTeX document and compiling with pdflatex, I frequently have compile errors. To get out of pdflatex when running it from the command line, I use the `exit` command to end the pdflatex process:

```
$ pdflatex kevin.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
<snip>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.276 ...2' \ldots c_j'\}$, $w \notin \{q_1 \lodts
    q_i\}$. $S \cap T$ is alw...
? exit
```

Once I use the exit command, pdflatex immediately brings up my tex document in vim. Is there any way to prevent this? I don't want pdflatex to open any text editor whatsoever when I exit it. I want the command line terminal to return to the shell and wait for more input. (I'm using a different text editor for editing, and having to close vim every time it opens after an error just wastes my time and is getting annoying.)

Comment: Why do you go to the effort of typing `exit` rather than just Ctrl-D to end the run?

Comment: I can just do that? =P

Comment: When I first started using pdflatex, I mistakenly used Ctrl-Z to end runs, meaning that I had many instances of pdflatex running uselessly in the background. My first thought when I realized my mistake was to try to find a way to close pdflatex with a command, which is why I'm now in the habit of using `exit`. If using Ctrl-D is the typical way to close pdflatex, I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When TeX, in interactive mode, shows the `?` prompt after an error, you have a few choices, but you should keep in mind that ***the first*** character you type determines the subsequent behavior:

- return means “ignore the error and proceed”
- `s` means “run showing future error messages without stopping except for requesting user input”
- `r` means “run showing future error messages, stopping if user input is required”
- `q` means “run quietly” (without showing anything)
- `i` means “insert something in the input stream”
- `x` means “stop here”
- `e` means “stop here and open the editor on the file at the current line number”
- a digit

In case you type `i`, TeX will insert the tokens you type after it until hitting return (which will count as a space); if you immediately hit return, you'll be prompted for the tokens to insert.

In case you type a digit, TeX will determine a `<number>` based on its rules from the subsequent characters you type. Hitting return will ignore `<number>` tokens from the input stream and TeX will stop again showing the ignored tokens, waiting for further input. Except in cases of `i` and of a digit, extra characters will be ignored.

So, typing `exit` is exactly the same as typing `e`, which has the behavior you are experiencing.

The correct way for exiting is typing `x`.

Note that lowercase or uppercase is irrelevant, so `S` `R` `Q` `I` `X` `E` have the same effect as `s` `r` `q` `i` `x` `e`.

On some implementations, hitting control-`D` will trigger the “emergency stop”, basically similar to typing `x`. On some implementations, hitting `e` is the same as typing `x`, but not in TeX Live, which will use the current value of the environment variable `TEXEDIT` for opening the file (if set in the environment). The value can be also set in the top level `texmf.cnf` file. For instance, my top level `texmf.cnf` file is

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf
TEXMFVAR = ~/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG = ~/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-config
TEXEDIT = nano +%d '%s'
```

so typing `e` will open the file in `nano`.